# Print row and column for multiple elements in a matrix given that the indices

Tags: r

suppose i have a sample as follows :

```
x <- matrix(sample(100,replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)
```

and a vector that contains the indices that i would like to access as follows

```
indices <- c(22,23,55,2)
```

how can i get the row and column of these indices ?

I thought maybe this would help

```
which(m == m[indices], arr.ind = TRUE)
```

but it only returns the first index. Im assuming what i've done there is wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
> for (indices in unique(indices)){
+       print(which(m == m[indices], arr.ind = TRUE))
+ }
     row col
[1,]   4   1
[2,]   2   7
[3,]  10   8
```

Answer (score 0):

While Hack-R's solution is great. It might provide you several results per index if any other variable in the x has the same value as x[index]

```
set.seed(100)
x <- matrix(sample(100,replace = TRUE), nrow = 10)
indices <- c(22,23,55,2)


for (indices in unique(indices)){
       print(which(x == x[indices], arr.ind = TRUE))
 }

     row col
[1,]   2   3
     row col
[1,]   1   3
[2,]   3   3
     row col
[1,]   5   6
[2,]   9   6
[3,]   2   9
     row col
[1,]   2   1
[2,]   6   6
```

This is probably not the behavior expected.
Furthermore resetting 'indices' with each loop is probably unfavorable.

One solution is to create temp copy of the matrix. Set all values except of those indices to zero and then compare to get location of these indices only.

```
temp <- x
temp[-(indices)] <- 0
which(temp > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)

     row col
[1,]   2   1
[2,]   2   3
[3,]   3   3
[4,]   5   6
```

Note: It returns results in the increasing order of indices:

```
sort(indices)
[1]  2 22 23 55
```